# Filter an Access Webform based on current SharePoint User

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, webforms, filtering

Building an issues log MS Access 2010 database that is linked to my organization's SharePoint 2010 site. I want everyone in my organization to be able to submit an issue into the database via a webform I have created. I am also building a Submitter's Log webform so people can see that status of the issues they have submitted. What is the language to filter the form based on current user? I thought it would be this below but that didn't work.

```
Filter| SharePointAuthor = [Me]
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured this out on my own. My web form was taking its data from a normal (non-web) query and so I created a web query and put "CurrentWebUser(1)" in the criteria under the SharePointAuthor field. The "1" returns the display name. A "0" gives current user’s member ID, "2" gives current user’s login name, and "3" gives current user’s e-mail address.

I learned that latter part from this site: http://accesshosting.com/demystifying-currentwebuserx